# BEM - applying contextual styles to the block inside another block

Tags: css, sass, bem

Suppose we have `.container` and `.button` blocks:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- some html -->
  <a class="button">A Marvelous button</a>
</div>
```

How should we approach styling of the `.button` block exclusively in `.container`'s context? Should we still create a `.button--modifier`?

Comment: How about `.container .button`?, unless you have more than one in there, then an individual class would be good ... or did I misunderstood anything

Comment: Thought about that, but is it the BEM way of solving the problem?

Comment: Well, no, they suggest what you questioned, using a `.button--modifier` .... Check this link: http://getbem.com/naming/

Comment: Sorry, can't find where exactly it is mentioned. Would you mind to clarify?

Comment: Can't explain it better than they already do in that link ... and honestly, haven't actually dived into it enough to give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case if the button will be (re)used elsewhere, within different sections then I would say style it .button--modifier. Check out the atomic design pattern (http://patternlab.io/), in this case a button would be an atom and the container likely a molecule. I think it is a good idea to style all reusable atoms in a .atom--modifier way but it would be good to hear other's views on this

Comment: What if that particular styling won't be used anywhere else?

Comment: In that case, the button style is specific to the component and .container__button might be more appropriate.

Comment: I think `.container__button` might really be a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use [mixes](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes) to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The case you have suggested means the .container IS the modifier of basic .button block.

The existing --modifiers that work outside of .containers context will still be relevant inside the .container context.

This also means you if you want to have two button styles inside .container you can change the existing .button--modifier based on the .container context without having to create a whole new --modifier for .button :)

sass example:

```
.button { 
  color: red;
  &--modifier {
    color:yellow // works everywhere including inside .container
  }
  .container & {
    color: green;
    &--modifier {
       color:blue; // just applied inside .container
    }
  }
}
```

will out put:

```
.button {
  color: red;
}
.button--modifier {
  color: yellow;
}
.container .button {
  color: green;
}
.container .button--modifier {
  color: blue;
}
```

as seen here http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9c909d0071bdac75dc1b73be86443e2c

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm not sure, that changing the button modifier based on the container's context is a good idea. It introduces implicit behavior, which in turn defeats the whole purpose of using BEM